# css3 transition on background

Tags: css

**SHORT EXPLANATION: I want to have a background-image on `opacity 0` until you hover and it becomes to `opacity: 1` with a `ease` transformation**

I am trying to display a background-image while the user hover the chart (it must be visible), but I can't figure out how to hide the background-image with `opacity: 0` and display it on `:hover` with `opacity: 1` transformation.

[DEMO (updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/37/)

CSS3:

```
#canvas {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 3s ease opacity;
     transition: .3s ease opacity;
}

#canvas:hover {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="450"></canvas>
```

What am I missing exactly?

Comment: Not seeing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/MU9aw/35/

Comment: Updated the fiddle (first one got opacity: 0)

Comment: @XaviAlsina Are you trying to fade one background image and reveal a different one on hover?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do or, precisely, what the issue is. You can't transition background-image properties if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: CSS transitions are unable to change background colors(i.e. the alpha-channel of a rgba() color). They can only work on numeric values, such as the overall opacity of the element. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yep, it was exactly wanting to do that, so if can't... I do not want to waste your time! Thanks for your answers! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I did some research, you are missing a direction. You can't use `-webkit-transitions to ease without a direction. You need to change it up just a little bit.

Original:

```
#canvas {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 3s ease opacity;
     transition: .3s ease opacity;
}

#canvas:hover {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Fixed:

```
#canvas {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

#canvas:hover {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

No it will smoothly transition from 0 to 1. If you need any help, please let me know.

Comment: I am not sure what your asking then.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a transition to zero to one, or no.

Comment: Added a short explanation

Comment: I have fixed an answer to your question

Comment: I am trying to make it work on the following demo but it does not: http://jsfiddle.net/MU9aw/68/ Anyway do not worry, I solved it with background-position, instead of opacity. Thank you for your time anyway!